# $(document).height() - changing value after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, viewport

Im trying to detect how many precent of the document has scrolled.
Made a `$(window).scroll` eventListener.

When im logging the `$(document).height()`  outside and inside the event function, im getting a larger num from inside the function.

it seems like **outside**, its logging the window height, and not the document since its always the same.

Comment: `$(window).height()` gets you an unit-less pixel value of the height of the (browser) window aka viewport. With respect to the web browsers the viewport here is visible portion of the canvas(which often is smaller than the document being rendered).

`$(document).height()` returns an unit-less pixel value of the height of the document being rendered. However, if the actual document’s body height is less than the viewport height then it will return the viewport height instead. -- maybe you do want to get `$(window).height()` instead?

Comment: In this situation the document is higher than the window, so the user can scroll down.